Why did James not defend Paul? Does James failing to defend Paul mean that James' faith is one without works?
I am pondering this question and would like other people's help/thoughts.  James, the brother of Jesus, author of the Epistle of James and leader of the early Jerusalem church, writes in the book of James, "Faith without works is dead."  He clearly sees that faith leads a person to action.  Yet, in Acts 21, Paul comes to Jerusalem and James tells Paul to perform the Jewish ritual of purification so that other Jews do not wrongly judge Paul as being anti-law.  Paul does what James asks, but the plan does not go well. Paul is nearly killed and is imprisoned.  Here is my question - why did James not support Paul when he was arrested?  Where is James' faith in action supporting and caring for Paul?

The epistle of James was written by James of Alphaeus, not James the natural brother of Jesus of Nazareth.

Clement of Alexandria from Stromata Book VIII Fragments begs to differ. "Jude, who wrote the Catholic Epistle, the brother of the sons of Joseph, and very religious, whilst knowing the near relationship of the Lord, yet did not say that he himself was His brother. But what said he? “Jude, a servant of Jesus Christ,”—of Him as Lord; but “the brother of James.” For this is true; he was His brother, (the son) of Joseph."

There's a lot of assumptions in your question that are not born out by the text in Acts 21 and elsewhere.
You say that " James tells Paul to perform the Jewish ritual of purification so that other Jews do not wrongly judge Paul as being anti-law. Paul does what James asks, but the plan does not go well. ". There is no evidence in the text that James' advice is the cause of the problems that Paul experiences. In fact the point of James advice is to forestall events like the one that happened. That the actions were not sufficient to prevent them does not make them bad advice.
There is nothing written to say that James did not support Paul when he was arrested. The actions you describe above were intended to prevent it, and he may well have done other things in support of Paul that are not recorded.
Even if James had failed to take action, a single failure does not invalidate his faith, or his teaching. If every Christian who had not done enough in a given circumstance were to be damned, not one of us would be saved. Fortunately God's grace is sufficient.

Thank you for your comments.  I agree that James probably could have done nothing at the time of arrest, but I am curious as to why James is not present (or a representative of the Jerusalem church) when Paul is brought before the council in Acts 23.   Paul does lament about being deserted (2 Timothy 4;16) and no one coming to his "first deference."  Regarding my assumptions - I do not think James sought to cause a problem, but it was still bad advice since it brought about the very situation the advice was supposed to avoid.

There is nothing in the passage that says James' advice "brought about" the situation, or that it wouldn't have happened just like that - or worse - if he hadn't given it.

Paul was in the temple doing exactly what James and the elders advised him to do when people accused Paul of polluting the temple and tried to kill him.  If that does not say "brought about" what would?

What the Christian Jerusalem council asked Paul to do was to sponsor the purification of 4 men who were fulfilling a vow so that the Jews could see, by Paul's actions, that he was not against the people, the law, or the temple as was suspected:

Do therefore what we tell you. We have four men who are under a vow; take these men and purify yourself along with them and pay their expenses, so that they may shave their heads. Thus all will know that there is nothing in what they have been told about you, but that you yourself also live in observance of the law. But as for the Gentiles who have believed, we have sent a letter with our judgment that they should abstain from what has been sacrificed to idols, and from blood, and from what has been strangled, and from sexual immorality.” - Acts 21:2-25

Perhaps James understood the principle underlying 1 Corinthians 9:18-23:

What is my reward then? Verily that, when I preach the gospel, I may make the gospel of Christ without charge, that I abuse not my power in the gospel. For though I be free from all men, yet have I made myself servant unto all, that I might gain the more. And unto the Jews I became as a Jew, that I might gain the Jews; to them that are under the law, as under the law, that I might gain them that are under the law; To them that are without law, as without law, (being not without law to God, but under the law to Christ,) that I might gain them that are without law. To the weak became I as weak, that I might gain the weak: I am made all things to all men, that I might by all means save some. And this I do for the gospel's sake, that I might be partaker thereof with you.

It was almost certainly understood by both of these men that Paul wasn't abrogating salvation by grace through faith and James was not asking him to do so.  Instead both were demonstrating faith in Christ, in that there is nothing wrong with participating in religious ceremonies so long as it is not done to obtain justification.  Neither is there anything wrong with abstaining from religious ceremonies when the true source of justification is acknowledged:

For in Christ Jesus neither circumcision nor uncircumcision counts for anything, but only faith working through love. - Galatians 5:6

What Paul was accosted for was the rumor of what he taught and, especially, of the rumor of bringing 'greeks' into the temple thereby defiling it.  Certainly James, as leader of the Church, was aware of how the Jews were riled up against Paul.  It probably made preaching the gospel to the Jews somewhat difficult and increasingly dangerous as well.

And when the seven days were almost ended, the Jews which were of Asia, when they saw him in the temple, stirred up all the people, and laid hands on him, Crying out, Men of Israel, help: This is the man, that teacheth all men every where against the people, and the law, and this place: and further brought Greeks also into the temple, and hath polluted this holy place. (For they had seen before with him in the city Trophimus an Ephesian, whom they supposed that Paul had brought into the temple.) - Acts 21:27-29

Additionally, it was the Romans who stepped in and stopped the Jewish mob from killing Paul on the spot (starting at verse 21).  James, a Jewish Christian, was not likely to have much of a voice in the Roman proceedings against Paul and he might endanger the entire Church by attempting to interfere.
James, as a Jewish Christian, was also unlikely to have much of a voice with the Pharisees, Sadducees, and Jewish leaders either since we know from much earlier in the book of Acts that preaching in the name of Jesus invoked persecution.
Lastly, what was James to have done since this capture of Paul by the Jews and his deliverance over to Roman power was a literal fulfillment of prophesy (which it is possible that Paul made known to them when he first reported to the council in 21:18-19):

And as we tarried there many days, there came down from Judaea a certain prophet, named Agabus. And when he was come unto us, he took Paul's girdle, and bound his own hands and feet, and said, Thus saith the Holy Ghost, So shall the Jews at Jerusalem bind the man that owneth this girdle, and shall deliver him into the hands of the Gentiles. - Acts 21:10-11


"OP: He [James] clearly sees that faith leads a person to action.
To understand the relationship of James (brother by flesh, same mother, different father) to Jesus and then to those of following years, you cannot agree with the idea that Mary remained an ever-virgin.
James had a powerful influence as the physical brother of Jesus.

Jude, who wrote the Catholic Epistle, the brother of the sons of Joseph, and very religious, whilst knowing the near relationship of the Lord, yet did not say that he himself was His brother. But what said he? “Jude, a servant of Jesus Christ,”—of Him as Lord; but “the brother of James.” For this is true; he was His brother, (the son) of Joseph. from Clement of Alexandria

So, when James asks/tells Paul to still observe the Mosaic Law, Paul obliges.

OP: why did James not support Paul when he was arrested? Where is James' faith in action supporting and caring for Paul?

It is clear to me the power struggle.  The battle between the Old and New didn't simply disappear easily and without a fight.  James apparently maintained the Mosaic Law position with a dollop of grace and massive authority, being the brother by the flesh of Jesus.
TO ADD TO CLARIFY THE POWER STRUGGLE.
It really wasn't about men per se, but about the "new" Way and the old.  It was, however, still men who steered things.

and he [God of our fathers] said unto me [Paul], Go, because to nations [Gentiles] far off I will send thee.' Acts 22:21

The reaction?

And they were hearing him unto this word, and they lifted up their voice, saying, 'Away from the earth with such an one; for it is not fit for him to live.'

Where's James' voice to still the crowd?
They are still zealous for the Mosaic Law.  Here's James a few days or so earlier.

And when he [Paul] had saluted them [James and elders], he declared particularly what things God had wrought among the Gentiles by his ministry. Acts 21:19


And when they heard it, they glorified the Lord, and said unto him, Thou seest, brother, how many thousands of Jews there are which believe; and they are all zealous of the law: Acts 21:20

Huh?  Paul talks about God's salvation to the nations and they respond the Jews are zealous for the law.
In addition, we know this.

For before that certain came from James, he [Peter] did eat with the Gentiles: but when they [from James] were come, he withdrew and separated himself, fearing them which were of the circumcision. Gal 2:12

What's the problem, Paul?

Knowing that a man is not justified by the works of the law, but by the faith of Jesus Christ, even we have believed in Jesus Christ, that we might be justified by the faith of Christ, and not by the works of the law: for by the works of the law shall no flesh be justified. Gal 2:16

To conclude, it is clear to me that there was a power struggle.  It is also clear to me that it was over the question of how does one become and stay justified; is it by faith in Jesus Christ or is it by works of the law?  The answer should be the same for both Jew and Gentile.

OP: why did James not support Paul when he was arrested?

By the time of this arrest, James son of Zebedee was beheaded.  There was unrest from all parties.  Perhaps James reasoned it would be better to stay alive with his perceived mission to the Jews.  We do not know for sure, but as shown above, there was a power struggle between the factions.

OP: Where is James' faith in action supporting and caring for Paul?

Faith in action may take a number of paths.  Not all are called to go to jail for their beliefs.  One may, however, question to what was James' faith directed, to the Mosaic Law or to Jesus Christ?

There were certainly conflicts in the early church, even among the apostles and other leaders, but I see no justification for perceiving any such conflict in the present text, much less one that could reasonably be characterized as part of a power struggle.  And if you're trying to suggest that James purposefully stood aside, allowing Paul to be arrested and held by the Roman authorities, for the purpose of maintaining his own power and authority over the church, then I flatly and utterly reject the idea.  There is no support for that in scripture.

I said, "it is clear to me".  That it is not clear to you is okay by me.
